# Difference between Tensor and tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am working with Pytorch. But when I use `tensor` I got an error while I don't get any error when I use `Tensor`.

What is the difference between Tensor and tensor?

This is my example:

```
tns = torch.tensor([91,21,34,56])

tns.mean()
```

I got this error:

> RuntimeError: Can only calculate the mean of floating types. Got Long
> instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a `dtype` in `torch.tensor()` it infers this from the data. Since your data is all integers, it used `Long`.

`torch.mean()` can only be calculated for floats.

By default, `torch.Tensor` is an alias for `torch.FloatTensor` hence it automatically has dtype float (unless you change the default behaviour).

Comment: Thank you, I got it and make it as below:

tns = torch.tensor([91,21,34,56],dtype=torch.float64)

tns.mean()